# how to splice a reference array using perl?

Tags: perl

how to splice a reference array using perl? I'm trying to remove certain elements from a reference array used in a function.

```
    &removeELement(@spliceArray);

    sub removeELement
    {
        my $ref_to_spliceArray = shift;

        foreach my $i (0 .. $#$ref_to_spliceArray)
        {
              if($ref_to_spliceArray->[$i] == /failed/)
              {
                    splice $ref_to_spliceArray->[$i],1; # this syntax does not work...
              }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the desired behavior with a couple of changes to your code.

- If you delete an element of the array, the index of the next element is now the same as the old value’s index. You can’t blindly iterate over `0 .. $#ref_to_spliceArray`.
- The regex bind operator is `=~` and not `==`.
- Attempted regex matches against the undefined value may trigger warnings.
- Pass an array to `splice`, not an individual element of the array.

The code below fixes these issues.

```
sub removeElement
{
  my $ref_to_spliceArray = shift;

  my $i = 0;
  while ($i <= $#$ref_to_spliceArray)
  {
    if (defined $ref_to_spliceArray->[$i]
          && $ref_to_spliceArray->[$i] =~ /failed/)
    {
      splice @$ref_to_spliceArray, $i, 1;
    }
    else {
      ++$i;
    }
  }
}
```

Modify your call to be

```
&removeElement(\@spliceArray);
```

Note that this syntax will appear archaic to modern eyes. Think about operating on the array as a whole rather than peeking and poking one element at a time. In this simple case, you don’t need to go to the trouble of defining another sub.

```
@spliceArray = grep !(defined && /failed/), @spliceArray;
```

That is, `@spliceArray` should contain only those elements that do not match the regex. The `defined` check prevents warnings about undefined values that may be present in `@spliceArray`.

Answer (score 0):

For using `splice` correctly, I'd suggest taking a look at the [`splice` man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html).

If using a reference, just dereference it: `@$aref` instead of just `$aref`.

For solving the problem at hand, consider using [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) instead. Here's an example using the Windows (double-quotes!) command-line:

```
perl -lwe "$x = [qw/a b failed d/]; print for grep ! m/failed/, @$x"
```

One more thing: use regular expressions with `=~` and `!~`, not `==`.

And you are using [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html), aren't you? Always `use strict`, always!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `grep`for this:

```
my @array = qw/foo bar baz qux/;
@array = grep { ! m/baz/ } @array;
# @array now contains foo bar qux
```

Your code has several mistakes:

- `==` isn't the same thing as `=~`
- You did not specify the offset and length to splice (eg. `splice $@aray, $i, 1`)
- After splice removed and element from your array the index `$i` will be incorrect, because you removed and item from the array and you'll be checking your array against elements which will not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a bad idea to try to remove elements from a list you are iterating over. Try using `grep` to create a new list containing only those elements you want to keep, and assign back to the original reference.

```
sub removeElement {
    my $ref_to_Array = shift;

    @$ref_to_Array = grep { ! /failed/ } @$ref_to_array;
}

&removeElement(\@someArray);
```

Notice you need to pass a *reference* to your array to the function.

The call to `splice` you were probably looking for, by the way, was

```
splice @$ref_to_spliceArray, $i, 1
```